# Data frame numeric column coerced into character vector when extracted with apply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Consider the following example:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c"), b = 1:3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data$b
# [1] 1 2 3

apply(data, 1, function(i) i['b'])
# [1] "1" "2" "3"

class(data$b)
# [1] integer

class(apply(data, 1, function(i) i['b']))
# [1] character

apply(data, 1, function(i) class(i['b']))
# [1] "character" "character" "character"
```

This does not happen when the data frame contains only integer-class columns.  It is my understanding that `apply` coerces the output to the lowest denominator (character in the example) rather than the actual output (integer in the example).  However, this appears to occur within the closure defined in `FUN` (as can be seen in the last command.)

Is it a bug or is this expected behaviour?  If this is indeed a design specification, can someone explain to me in what scenarios this makes sense?  Are there any ways around this without having to add an `as.integer` conversion in each function definition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. (3rd line of code throws an error).

Comment: Read the first sentence of the Details section of `?apply` and keep in mind that matrices can only hold a single data type, unlike data frames. Many people misuse `apply` in this fashion.

Comment: @joran Your comment sounds like an answer to me.  The details section does say that.  Put it up and I'll accept it.  Thanks!